# A simple & quick note taking application that runs in tray?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a simple & quick note taking application that does the following:

1. Can start minimised in tray on startup
2. Opens a minimal text composing interface when the user clicks on the tray icon
3. Minimises back to tray and automatically saves the composed text when the user clicks on the window close button (the X in the corner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is something like a Sticky Note.

There are a few available you can try:

- [indicator-stickynotes](http://launchpad.net/~umang/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-stickynotes)
- Sticky Notes: It is the default sticky note application for Gnome. It is an applet that you add on the panel and access it via a simple click on the panel icon.
- KNotes: Knotes is the default sticky note app in Linux KDE desktop.
- XPad

More Info: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-little-useful-sticky-notes-app-for-linux/

Comment: Thanks! I tried XPad but it doesn't show a tray icon on Ubuntu 16.10 Unity. Does it for you?

Comment: Maybe you can try indicator-stickynotes. 

https://launchpad.net/~umang/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-stickynotes

Comment: This one is great! Do you want to add it to your answer?

Comment: Sure I'll update it